# compile object code in linux error (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Tags: objective-c, linux, compilation, g++, syntax-error

im triying to compile a object from the source 
http://xeat-engine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
using the code

g++ -c `wx-config --cxxflags` main.cpp

g++ -o main main.o `wx-config --libs`

and obtain the error

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

please help me to fix the problem
What could I do?
IS A CAPTURE FOR MAIN.CPP

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TziYb.jpg

Comment: Could you show at least a snippet of main.cpp and any possible headers showing your wxApp-derived class and the `wxIMPLEMENT_APP()` macro? It may help diagnosis.

Comment: OK                                                                   , THINK I HAVE TO COMPILE AND LINKING https://sites.google.com/a/case.edu/hpc-upgraded-cluster/home/important-notes-for-new-users/compiling--linking ALL FILES ARE IN THIS LINK http://xeat-engine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: As I noticed you were using wxWidgets, I referred to: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_helloworld.html --- "As in all programs there must be a 'main' function. Under wxWidgets 'main' is implemented using this macro, which creates an application instance and starts the program." --- The main() function is defined behind the scenes.

Comment: @VictorHernandez hi, how do you fix this problem? I'm also having the same problem but I don't have any knowledge about c++. I follow the answer: change `IMPLEMENT_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);` to `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);` in `gui/xeatengine_gui.h`. still same error... Could you paste your changes?

Comment: some typo in the previous comment. Here is what I change: change `IMPLEMENT_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);` to `wxIMPLEMENT_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);` in `gui/xeatengine_gui.cpp` and add `wxDECLARE_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);` in `gui/xeatengine_gui.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing:

```
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);
```

which will be expanded into a valid `main()` function.

***NOTE:*** the trailing semicolon *is* necessary...

See also:

```
wxDECLARE_APP(xeatengine_guiApp);
```